# How to Reduce Image Size (Taken For Camera ) before Uploading to Firebase

Tags: android, bitmap

In Android I am taking image from camera as usually its around 5-6 MB. So I want to Reduce this Image size before uploading. 
Can't it be done using library like Picasso or Glide

Comment: Please add some code that you may have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (CAMERA_REQUEST == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap uri = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            uri.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70, baos);
            //then you can handle the firebase upload here.
         }
      }
```

Bitmap class in android has this method `.compress` to achieve what you want here.The details of the method are as:

```
compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)
```

Read more about it on the developers site :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Hope that helps